# Migration from PostgreSQL to Mysql - Invalid timestamp literal detected

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am using MysqlWorkBench to migrate a PostGreSQL database, but I'm running into issues with the timestamp columns.

The PostgreSQL database is using created_at columns with "timestamp without timezone" column type, which includes milliseconds. MySQL does not have that format.

What format should I try converting it to in order to get it to run?

I'm using MySQL v5.6 and PostGreSQL 9.3.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the precision for your datetimes with a number of decimals in parenthesis. Your type declaration in MySQL would be this 'DATETIME(3)' for millisecond precision. Also, MySQL format for datetimes doss not handle the time zone annotations after the time, so make sure you remove those. For example '2016-01-01 02:30:14.456+00' from Postgres should be changed to '2016-01-01 02:30:14.456'.